# $\left(i\sqrt {\frac{21 \ + \ 5\sqrt{5}}{2}}\right)^n \notin \Bbb{Q}(ζ_{11})$ for all positive integer $n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, cyclotomic-fields, ramification

I want to prove $\left(i\sqrt {\frac{21 \ + \ 5\sqrt{5}}{2}}\right)^n$ does not lie in $\Bbb{Q}(ζ_{11})$ for all positive integer $n$.

This problem arises from arithmetic geometry, but this problem itself is purely a field theoretic one.

For $n$ is even, this is equivalent to $\sqrt{5}\notin \Bbb{Q}(ζ_{11})$. But if $\sqrt{5}\in \Bbb{Q}(ζ_{11})$, prime ideal above $5$ will not be unratified, but from class field theory, prime ideal above $5$ does not ramify, this is a contradiction.

But I'm sticking with the case that $n$ is odd.

Comment: Hint: consider $\left(i\sqrt{\frac{21+5\sqrt{5}}{2}}\right)^{2n}$.

Comment: Galois theory tells us that $\Bbb{Q}(\zeta_{11})$ has a unique quadratic subfield. Gauss sums tell us that the field in question is $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{-11})$. As $11$ is the only ramified prime, your fancier machinery points in the same direction.

Comment: @Aphelli Let $K_n=\left(i\sqrt {\frac{21 \ + \ 5\sqrt{5}}{2}}\right)^n$. Considering $\left(i\sqrt {\frac{21 \ + \ 5\sqrt{5}}{2}}\right)^{2n}$, $K_1\notin \Bbb{Q}(ζ_{11})$ or $K_{2k+1}\notin \Bbb{Q}(ζ_{11})(k≧1)$ holds. But I cannot proceed from here. One more hint ?

Comment: If $K_n \in \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{11})$, then so is $K_{2n}$…

Comment: @Aphelli, Jyrki Lhtonen, reuns.   Thank you for your really helpful comments. I answered my self combining your help. If it is not incorrect, I'm glad if you notify me.

Comment: If it is not correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\left(i\sqrt {\frac{21 \ + \ 5\sqrt{5}}{2}}\right)^n\in \Bbb{Q}(\zeta_{11})$ then $\left(i\sqrt {\frac{21 \ + \ 5\sqrt{5}}{2}}\right)^{2n}=(-\frac{21 \ + \ 5\sqrt{5}}{2})^n \in \Bbb{Q}(\zeta_{11})$.

$Gal(\Bbb{Q}(\zeta_{11})/\Bbb{Q})$ is cyclic so $\Bbb{Q}(\zeta_{11})$ has a unique quadratic subfield, which is $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{-11})$.

So we get that $(21 \ + \ 5\sqrt{5})^n\in \Bbb{Q}(\zeta_{11})\cap \Bbb{Q}(\sqrt5)=\Bbb{Q}$.

Take the non-trivial automorphism $\sigma\in Gal(\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt5)/\Bbb{Q})$ such that $ \sigma(21 \ + \ 5\sqrt{5})=21 \ - \ 5\sqrt{5}$.

If $(21 +  5\sqrt{5})^n\in \Bbb{Q}$ then $(21 + 5\sqrt{5})^n=\sigma((21 +  5\sqrt{5})^n)=(21  -  5\sqrt{5})^n$ which is absurd as $|21 -  5\sqrt{5}|\ne |21  + 5\sqrt{5}|$.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose for some $n$,  $\left(i\sqrt {\frac{21 \ + \ 5\sqrt{5}}{2}}\right)^n$ lies in $\Bbb{Q}(ζ_{11})$.
Then  $\left(i\sqrt {\frac{21 \ + \ 5\sqrt{5}}{2}}\right)^{2n}=\left( {\frac{333 \ + \ 105\sqrt{5}}{2}}\right)^{n}\in \Bbb{Q}(ζ_{11})$.
So if we write $\left( {\frac{333 \ + \ 105\sqrt{5}}{2}}\right)^{n}=a+b \sqrt{5}$ for some $a,b \in \Bbb{Q}$, the last condition is equivalent to $\sqrt{5}\in \Bbb{Q}(ζ_{11})$.

Let's consider the prime ideal decomposition of $\sqrt{5}\Bbb{Z}[ζ_{11}]$ in $\Bbb{Q}(ζ_{11})$.

$\sqrt{5}\Bbb{Z}[ζ_{11}]=P_1^eP_2^e\cdots P_n^e$ ($P_1,P_2,...,P_n$ are prime ideals of $\Bbb{Z}[ζ_{11}]$ and $e$ is the ramification index), so $(5)= P_1^{2e}P_2^{2e}\cdots P_n^{2e}$.
In particular, $(5)$ is not unramified.

On the other hand, from well known ramification property of cyclotomic fields, $(5)$ is unramified. This is a contradiction.

Comment: In theory it might happen that in the expansion
$$\left(\frac{333+105\sqrt5}2\right)^n=a+b\sqrt{5}$$ you might get $b=0$. In that case you could not conclude that $\sqrt5\in\Bbb{Q}(\zeta_{11})$. The solution by reuns clears that problem neatly using an automorphism of $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt5)$ together with uniqueness of the quadratic intermediate field.